# MySql query column in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

I have OrderTbl table with OrdNo, OrdDate,  OrdState, CustNo and other columns and Customer table with CustNo, CustFirstName, CustState and other columns. And I need to select all of them but when I am writing a query

```
  select OrdNo, OrdDate,  OrdState, CustFirstName, CustState, CustNo from OrderTbl,Customer
```

MySQl gives me an error than mu CustNo column is ambiguous and I understand that it because CustNo in both tables..But what  can I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two tables, which *both* have a column called `CustNo`. How should MySQL know what column you want?

Also, you would want to join the tables correctly:

```
select o.OrdNo, o.OrdDate,  o.OrdState, c.CustFirstName, c.CustState, c.CustNo 
from 
     OrderTbl o
join Customer c
on 
     o.CustNo = c.CustNo
```

What you need to do, is using table *aliases* or explicitly addressing the columns you want to read.

```
-- alternative to the query above without aliases
select OrderTbl.OrdNo, OrderTbl.OrdDate,  OrderTbl.OrdState, Customer.CustFirstName, Customer.CustState, Customer.CustNo 
from 
     OrderTbl
join Customer
on 
     OrderTbl.CustNo = Customer.CustNo
```